# Is there any value for a repository to return an iterator rather than a list?

Tags: repository

I see a pattern where the get method from a repository returns an Iterable, even if the list is composed already:

```
def get() -> Iterable[type]:
  my_list = [list]
  for x in my_list:
    yield x
```

I'm wondering what are the benefits of this pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many possibilities. For instance, if you implement a `get()` as part of a larger set of interfaces (think the Java collection classes), then there is value in *always* returning the more flexible type even though in this particular class, you're not exploiting the flexibility. The advantage is that a user of your class doesn't have to wonder "Was this one of the old-fashioned bits, or do I get an Iterable?".

In other words, a library should strive to *reduce cognitive load* for the user to make programming the entire system a bit less error-prone. (It may not seem like much, but reducing cognitive load is in fact the *major* reason why libraries are a good idea in the first place. It's not just that you won't *have time* to implement all helper functionality yourself; it's that you *can't think on all those levels simultaneously* well enough to build a solid system without abstracting away some of the details.)

Comment: This explains why you want consistency, even if the API is capable of returning a list. But, why are any of your API's not just returning lists to begin with?

Comment: Because you might want to prevent the caller from doing anything else than iterating. You don't want the developer to alter (or try to) the data structure in any way (size & order). Reasons? Determinism by immutability. The right data structure for the right job.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's part of the answer, IMO. "Consistency is good. And some API's should iterators because ..., therefore, there would be some benefit to always returning an iterator." (I mean, what you said, but also what gnasher's answer says.)

Answer (score 5):

In some libraries, an iterator can have unlimited capacity. For example, in Swift you can create an iterator returning all the prime numbers, one by one. That's not quite possible with a list. You can also have an iterator that only acquires its elements when they are needed. Lets say items in a databases ordered by similarity to some item. Most likely we need only the first few items in the list. We can do limited work with an iterator and do more work only if needed; returning a list we'd have to create the full list.

Comment: This + Killian's answer = the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

(Because your example uses Python syntax, I'm going to keep it relevant to Python. Other programming languages may have different semantics and pragmatics which would change the answer.)

If you have a class that maintains a list as part of its internal state, it might not want to directly expose that list, because lists are mutable and as such users of that class may accidentally leave instances of that class in an inconsistent state.

To solve that, instead of returning a reference to the state, the programmer can e.g. return a copy of the list, a special proxy object, or an iterator over the list.

Each has its upsides and downsides. The advantage of the iterator approach is that it is lightweight (if you only need 1 or 2 entries in the state, you don't have to make a copy of the whole list). The same goes for a proxy, but an iterator is simpler, and Python users are expected to know what to do with iterators.

(A generator function is in essence simply a function that returns an iterator.)